# Execute a Query After Call a stored procedure

Tags: c#

This is my stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_CPC`(
    IN _B VARCHAR(100),
    IN _G      VARCHAR(2),     
    IN _R VARCHAR(30), 
    IN _D VARCHAR(30), 
    OUT _C FLOAT, 
    OUT _P FLOAT)
BEGIN
  //Something Hear
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I Call this stored procedure by C# flowing Code

```
DataSet tmpDataSet = new DataSet();
mCommand.CommandText = "sp_CPC";
mCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
// mCommand.CommandText = "sp_select_all_employees";
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_B", "bty-23");
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_G", "3");
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_R", "9000");
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_D", "92");

mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_C",MySqlDbType.Float);
mCommand.Parameters["@_C"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
mCommand.Parameters.Add("@_P", MySqlDbType.Float);
mCommand.Parameters["@_P"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

try
{
    mConnection.Open();
    mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mAdapter.Fill(tmpDataSet)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    strErrorInfo = ex.ToString();
}
finally
{
    mConnection.Close();
}
DataTable dtb = tmpDataSet.Tables[0];
         mCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO abc (xxxx,yyyy) VALUES ('" + dtb.Rows[0][0] + "','" + dtb.Rows[0][1] + "')";           
         mConnection.Open();
         mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();     
         mConnection.Close();
return tmpDataSet;
```

it show error  in this command  mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-14' AND name LIKE '5378377032052','6'' at line 1.

(Return tmpDataSet) use  Because of this data i also use anouther work

Comment: Where did you write code to execute query?

Comment: If the `INSERT` is the problem, please show the code of the `INSERT` and also give detailed information about the error that occurs. As you give detailed information about the SP that runs before, you must be convinced that this information is relevant. Why do you think there is a connection between the SP and the `INSERT`?

Comment: Where did you put the insert? After the Close?

Comment: which data type you have been used for ID

Comment: I need Inset data a table which collect from this stored Procedure  i write this after Above Code
 
    DataTable dtb = tmpDataSet.Tables[0];
             mCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO abc (xxxx,yyyy) VALUES ('" + dtb.Rows[0][0] + "','" + dtb.Rows[0][1] + "')";           
             mConnection.Open();
             mCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();     
             mConnection.Close();
It show Error 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-14' AND name LIKE '5378377032052','6'' at line 1

Comment: @all Please see my code again i change my code

Answer (score 0):

The way you construct the `INSERT` statement is unsafe. You concatenate strings that might contain `'` characters, so that your `INSERT` statement becomes invalid - and also prone to SQL injection attacks. The error message you show in the comments points in this direction.

In order to solve this, use parameters in the `INSERT` statement as you did in your stored procedure.

Sample:

```
// ...
mCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO abc (xxxx,yyyy) VALUES (@val1, @val2)";           
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", dtb.Rows[0][0]);     
mCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", dtb.Rows[0][1]);
// ...
```